# How to specify the order of text detection

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-vision

I started using Google Vision API recently and have confronted a problem.
Chat-bot I've been working is a bill-recognition bot. So, it should scan the bill left-to-right downwards the image. I do all manipulations with recognized text after.
My text detection code is following:

```
const gcsPath = "https://api.telegram.org/file/bot427731672:AAHC6nkvnnSqYKHYaeZVSWY7itB0BGgv2Kw/" + photo.file_path;
            vision.textDetection({ source: {imageUri : gcsPath } })
            .then((results) => {
                const detections = results[0].textAnnotations;
                console.log('Text:');
                detections.forEach((text) => console.log(text.description));
                });
```

The console output often has no structure relatively to the image i.e for some image it can be left-to-right, for the other right-to-left. 
My question is, how do I set the hints, so the detection always has the direction?

Comment: Hi for the reason why people are using javascript and in particular ajax is for the ASYNC (asynchronous) action. So if you call something externally or run different process you can got resultat no in the order of your calls. To solve this problem you can use promise or adding some callback to the script to tell you the process is finished before other calls actions. Regards.

Comment: @headmax Thanks for the answer. Would you be so kind to propose me a code example?